# Linq to Lambda Expression c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var ListInOrder = (from f in finaldatelist
               group f by new { f.RoomID, f.RateGroupID } into g
               select g);
```

What are the lambda expression for the into g and select g part?

This is what I got now:

```
 var ListInOrder = finaldatelist.GroupBy(x => x.RoomID, x => x.RateGroupID).Select();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
finaldatelist.GroupBy(x => new { x.RoomID, x.RateGroupID });
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like,

```
var ListInOrder  = finaldatelist.GroupBy(cm => new { cm.RoomID, cm.RateGroupID}, 
             (key, group) => new { RoomID= key.RoomID, RateGroupID = 
              key.RateGroupID});
```

Comment: For doing that I will be just getting a result for two IDs. what if there are still other elements in fnaldatelist.

Comment: You need to add them or can just use GroupBy if you do not need specific fields